# Using the name resolver of resolv.h with IPv6

Tags: c, dns, ipv6

I write or modify programs which perform name resolution and need a
good control of the process. So I do not use `getaddrinfo()`, I go
deeper and use `res_query()` / `res_send()` / etc in `resolv.h`, documented
in resolver(3).

Although not documented, the common way to set the resolver used is to
update `_res.nsaddr_list`. But this array, defined in resolv.h, stores
`struct sockaddr_in`, that is IPv4 addresses only. (IPv6 addresses
are `struct sockaddr_in6`, a family-independant system would use `struct sockaddr`.)

I'm looking for a way (preferrably portable, at least among the
various Unix) to tell `_res` that I want also IPv6 addresses.

Apparently, a long time ago, there was in FreeBSD a `_res_ext` with this
ability but I cannot find it anymore in a recent FreeBSD 7 (`grep
_res_ext /usr/include/resolv.h` finds nothing). You can still find
[code which uses it](http://www.squid-cache.org/~hno/changesets/squid3/patches/5775.patch) (try yourself [with Google Codesearch](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q="_res_ext"+"nsaddr_list"&sbtn=Search)).

Thanks to Alnitak, I noticed it is apparently now `_res._ext` and not `.res_ext`. I wonder where these sort of things are documented or announced... I have no idea how portable `_res._ext` is. I can find it on Debian and FreeBSD. It seems there are few programs which use it.

Answer (score 2):

Stéphane - if your `resolv.h` doesn't include any support for `sockaddr_in6` then that suggests that on your particular O/S the resolver does not itself support IPv6 transport.

I've checked some of my systems here:

- MacOS X 10.5.6 - supports the BIND 9 library, which has a `res_setservers()` function which *can* take IPv6 addresses, no `_res._ext` extension.
- CentOS 5.2 - has the `_res._ext` extension, although there's no mention of IPv6 in the man page for `resolv.conf` except that there's a setting to tell the resolver to return AAAA records before looking for A records for `gethostbyname()`.

EDIT - also, the [CVS repository](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/include/resolv.h) for FreeBSD suggests that FreeBSD 7.0 (see tag `FREEBSD_7_0_0_RELEASE`) does also support `res_setservers()` from Bind 9.

Comment: But undocumented :-(

    susanna:~ % uname -r          
    7.0-RELEASE
    
    susanna:~ % man res_setservers
    No manual entry for res_setservers

Comment: I do not find `res_setservers` on Linux/glibc machines. I assume there is no standard for IPv6 resolution :-(

Comment: odd - it's in the resolv.h file :(.  The symbol does exist in Mac OS X, although it's really res_9_setservers and a #define gives access to the normal version.

Answer (score 1):

glibc:

```
res_setservers: no
__res_state._u._ext.nsaddrs
__res_state._u._ext.nsmap
```

set the latter to MAXNS+1 according to:

http://sourceware.org/ml/libc-hacker/2002-05/msg00035.html

BSD-libc:

```
res_setservers: yes
__res_state._u._ext.__res_state_ext
```

Seems messy to me and you'll probably need autoconf.