# Programmatically set DNS nameserver on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, dns, nameservers

I'd like to be able to add IP addresses for DNS nameservers on Linux from my C/C++ program.  I'm on a somewhat embedded platform with a read-only /etc/resolv.conf.  This means I can't simply add a "nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" line to the file without a little trickery.  Are there any clean ways to do this from code?

I could try symlinking /etc/resolv.conf to a file in tmpfs, but that seems hackish and it feels like something I should be able to do without writing to a file.

Comment: on an embedded platform or thinclient it is ok to symlink to /tmp.

Comment: Kinda hard to say without knowing what the capabilities of your embedded platform. But IMHO in embedded land sometimes beggars can't be choosers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `nsaddr_list` in [`resolv.conf`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=resolv/resolv.h;hb=2d0671cbbdade9013d6fd5153d01bd5e1d3f60cb#l109) from your libc.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388930/using-the-name-resolver-of-resolv-h-with-ipv6) says:

> Although not documented, the common way to set the resolver used is to update `_res.nsaddr_list`.

In uClibc 0.9.31 specifically there is a [comment on line 533](http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/inet/resolv.c?id=0.9.31#n533) in `resolv.c` describing how this works.

Comment: Good find.  That value contains my original nameserver value from resolv.conf as expected.  However, if I change it, my program still uses the value from resolv.conf.  I am using uClibc, though, and I suppose I can't expect them to support all the undocumented features of other libc's.

Comment: Seems in uClibc you need to call `res_init()` before doing this: see [the comment at line 538](http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/inet/resolv.c?id=0f4516e32c3a2186e6b6f074cfc6a57bde90e9cc#n538). Let me know if it works and I'll amend the answer.

Comment: I was calling res_init(), but  I'm stuck on [0.9.28](http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/inet/resolv.c?h=0_9_28), which didn't have that nice comment block you linked to.  In both instances, there is a __nameserver variable which feeds the nsaddr_list values from resolv.conf.  In my uClibc version, gethostbyname and friends pull directly from __nameserver; it's only the later versions that pull from nsaddr_list.  I'll happily accept your answer, as it got me where I needed to be and should actually be correct for most people.

Comment: Manipulating `nsaddr_list` like suggested is not working for me -- see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55724014