# Set DNS / Nameserver programatically and permanently on Linux

Tags: c, linux, dns, nameservers

I want to update the nameserver programmatically. 
In this question [programmatically-set-dns-nameserver-on-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034143/programmatically-set-dns-nameserver-on-linux) was mentioned to manipulate `_res.nsaddr_list` -- so I did.

```
void setNameServer(const std::string& rstr_addr)
{
  struct sockaddr_in x_addr;
  inet_pton(AF_INET,rstr_addr.c_str(),&x_addr.sin_addr);
  res_init();
  _res.nsaddr_list[0] = x_addr;
}
```

**This is not working.** `getaddrinfo` is now returning with error: "Name or service not known"

So there a basically two questions:

1. What is the correct way to set the nameserver ip programmatically
2. How to set it permanently in a proper way (ATM I just write it to `/etc/resolv.conf` by myself)

Comment: For Systemd-based systems see [`hostnamectl.c`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/hostname/hostnamectl.c). I believe systemd has an API, but I am not sure if hostname is exposed.

Comment: `struct sockaddr_in` is not the same as `struct in_addr`.

Comment: @stark absolutely correct, thanks, I corrected the code - but I still have the same problem